# Prove that every number is divisible by $1$ and that the only numbers that divide $1$ are $1$ and $-1$

Tags: proof-writing

> Prove that every number is divisible by $1$ and that the only numbers that divide $1$ are $1$ and $-1$
>
> axiom: if $d \mid n, \, \exists k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $d \cdot k = n$

for $1 \cdot k = n, \forall n \,\exists k$ such that $k = n \longrightarrow \forall n, \, 1 \mid n$

For the second part for $d \cdot k = 1$ there are two cases:
case 1: $k = 1 \longrightarrow d = 1$
case 2: $k = -1 \longrightarrow d = -1$

Does anybody have any feedback on this and my use of notation?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all need work ...

1. You need to be explicit about the fact that $1 \cdot n =n$. So:

Take any $n$. Since $1 \cdot n =n$, there exists some $k$ such that $1 \cdot k =n$. So, for any $n$: $1|n$

2 and 3. You need to show that there are no solutions for any other $k$.

Let $n$ divide $1$. That means that there exists some $k$ such that $n\cdot k =1$. Hence, $n = \frac{1}{k}$.

Now, if $k=0$, then $n\cdot k= n \cdot 0  =0 \not =1$. So, $k \not =0$.

If $k=1$, then $n=1$, so we have a solution for $k=1$ and $n=1$, so $1|1$.

If $k>1$, then from $n = \frac{1}{k}$ is not an integer, so there is no solution there.

If $k=-1$, then $n=\frac{1}{-1}=-1$, so solution there with $n=-1$.

If $k<-1$, then $n=\frac{1}{k}$ is not an integer.

This covers all possible values of $k$, so there are only two solutions: $n=1$ and $n=-1$. Hence, $1$ and $-1$ are the only numbers that divide $1$.

Comment: Yeah you're right. That's a more comprehensive answer. I had some unaddressed holes in mine.